# Does Skype have groups for contacts?

Tags: windows, skype

I'm running Skype 4.2.0.169.  I've seen mention of the contact grouping feature for older versions of skype, but I can't seem to find it in the current version. Was it removed, renamed something else, or well hidden?

Every other piece of chat software allows you to group contacts / screen names, so I would think Skype has it kicking around somewhere.

Any Ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I am also running 4.2.0.169.  Under the **Contacts** menu I have the item **Create New Group**.  That should give you what you're looking for.

The UI for the group isn't entirely intuitive however, you have to drag contacts from your contact list to an "Empy group" box, which appears in the upper right hand corner of the screen.  You can then save the group to your contact list to have it show up like any other contact.

Comment: Hm...it makes a "call group", rather than a group you can expand/contract to see who's in it.  Kind of an odd way to handle grouping.

Comment: A bit of follow-up. These are call groups, which don't act as groups in other chat clients.  When someone IMs you, other people in the same group automatically get added to the conversation.